# Loading images into canvas (HTML/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I know this has been discussed before and I've read many articles and tried what was claimed as working, so don't discard my question immediately, please.

I'm trying to load different images into a unified-size canvas. It can be a single image or multiple images, but I'm processing one image at a time.

Here is the main code (HTML/JS/PHP):

```
<?php
   if ($record->photo != "") //make the first canvas
   {
     list($width, $height, $type) = getimagesize($record->photo);
     echo "Width: " .$width. "<br />";
     echo "Height: " .$height. "<br />";
   ?>   
   <canvas id="my_canvas" width="341" height = "256"></canvas> 

   <body>
   <script  type="text/javascript" src="common.js"></script>
   <script  type="text/javascript">
    var img_src = "<?php echo $record->photo;?>";
    var width = "<?php echo $width;?>"; 
    var height = "<?php echo $height;?>"; 

    make_canvas('my_canvas', img_src, width, height);
   </script>

   <?php
   }//if 1
```

Similar block for canvas2, 3 etc. with closing  tag at the end.

Here are versions of make_canvas() function that "somehow" work.  Meaning they sometimes render some pictures on load but may improve on refresh. When there is more than one picture to display I never get it working properly.

Version 1 - inconsistent and caches the last image:

```
function make_canvas(id, src, width, height)
{

   if (width > 341) 
    {
        var new_width = 341;
        var ratio = new_width / width;
        var new_height = Math.round(height * ratio);
    }  
    else
    {
       var new_width = width;
       var new_height = height;
    }
    document.write("id: " + id + "<br />");
    document.write("src: " + src + "<br />");
    document.write("new_height: " + new_height + "<br />"); 

  var canvas = document.getElementById(id),
  context = canvas.getContext('2d');    
  base_image = new Image();
  //base_image.src = '';

  base_image.onload = function(){
      context.drawImage(base_image,0,0,new_width, new_height);
  }

     base_image.src = src; 
  }
```

Version 2 : may load one image and is caching it on refresh

```
function make_canvas2(id, src, width, height)
{

   if (width > 341) 
    {
        var new_width = 341;
        var ratio = new_width / width;
        var new_height = Math.round(height * ratio);
    }  
    else
    {
       var new_width = width;
       var new_height = height;
    }
    document.write("id: " + id + "<br />");
    document.write("src: " + src + "<br />");
    document.write("new_height: " + new_height + "<br />"); 

  var canvas = document.getElementById(id),
  context = canvas.getContext('2d');    
  base_image = new Image();
  base_image.src = '';
  base_image.addEventListener("load", function() {
  // execute drawImage statements here
  context.drawImage(base_image,0,0,new_width, new_height);
}, false);
  //base_image.onload = function(){ };

     base_image.src = src; 

}
```

I tried adding base_image.complete in IF condition for onload or to WHILE loop within the onload function but could never achieve multiple images displayed correctly on a first load.
I would appreciate any working examples , preferably similar to above and without jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I justed noted that you accidently defined a global image-object by writing this:

```
base_image = new Image();
```

Thats why the last image overwrites all former images while being loaded.

```
var base_image = new Image(); // this is fixed
```

Hope this example helps you, you can do most of all work via js. Just press the "run code snippet"-Button and tell me wether this is what you want:

```js
var imageUrls = [
  'http://animal-dream.com/data_images/koala/koala6.jpg',
  'https://i.stack.imgur.com/20n3G.jpg',
  'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/d/db/Das_G%C3%BCtermarktgleichgewicht_bei_einkommensabh%C3%A4ngiger_Nachfrage.jpg'
];
var canvasWidth = 341;
var canvasHeight = 256;

function create_canvas(id, width, height)
{
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.setAttribute('id',id);
  canvas.setAttribute('width',width);
  canvas.setAttribute('height',height);
  document.getElementById('canvasCon').appendChild(canvas);
}

function make_canvas(id, src, width, height)
{
  if (width > 341)
  {
    var new_width = 341;
    var ratio = new_width / width;
    var new_height = Math.round(height * ratio);
  } 
  else
  {
    var new_width = width;
    var new_height = height;
  }
  document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML += 'id: ' + id + '<br />src: ' + src + '<br /> new_height: ' + new_height + '<br />';
  var canvas = document.getElementById(id),
  context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var base_image = new Image();
  base_image.onload = function () {
    context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0, new_width, new_height);
  }
  base_image.src = src;
}

imageUrls.forEach(function(url,index){
  var canvasId = 'my_canvas'+(index+1);
  create_canvas(canvasId,canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
  make_canvas(canvasId, url, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
});
```

```html
<div id="msg"></div>
<div id="canvasCon"></div>
```

Comment: Blauharley, you saved my out of days of frustration! Small things (var) make big difference, everything started to work with version 1 of my make_canvas() (not tested cross-browser yet). And yes, your code is doing what I need. Many thanks!

Comment: You are welcome! Please mark my answer as right so that it becomes clear. Thank you.